# Matching several string matches from lists and making a new row for each match

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame with text in one of the columns and I am using regex formatted strings to see if I can find any matches from three lists. However, when there are multiple matches from list 1, I want to make make a duplicate column for each of the matches. The one caveat is that the matches must be in consecutive order, with elements from lists list_2 and list_3 being optional.

I have an example below for what I would like the desired output to be.

```
list_1 = ['chest', 'test', 'west', 'nest']
list_2 = ['mike', 'bike', 'like', 'pike']
list_3 = ['hay', 'day', 'may', 'say']
```

sample DF:

| text | match_1 | match_2 | match_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz | chest | bike | day |
| aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aaaa aaa | nest | NaN | NaN |
| ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ggg gggg west like | test | like | hay |

desired output:

| text | match_1 | match_2 | match_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz | chest | bike | day |
| zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz | test | mike | NaN |
| zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz | west | NaN | NaN |
| aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aaaa aaa | nest | NaN | NaN |
| aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aaaa aaa | nest | bike | may |
| ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ggg gggg west like | test | like | hay |
| ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ggg gggg west like | west | NaN | NaN |
| ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ggg gggg west like | west | like | NaN |

I hope my description above was not too confusing. My current method is unable to match for text that has several matches from list_1 (as shown in the example above) with the optional matches from list_2 and list_3 being consecutive.

Thanks for your all your efforts!

Comment: can you share what you have tried? and you are saying you need more than three columns if there are multiple matches?

Comment: I wrote a simple loop that iterates through each row of the df and each element of the of three lists and made a new column for when there was a single match. And no, there will never be more than 1 element from lists list_2 or list_3 when there is a match on an element from list_1 (so chest bike bike is not possible or test mike may say).

Comment: I am sorry I am not clear, what are you expecting as output when the input is "zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz "

Comment: The output  in three separate columns should be:                                                                                                                  chest bike day,                                                                                                                           test mike NaN,                                                                                                                            west NaN NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a regex programmatically from your word lists, using nested levels of optional parts to allow for possibly missing 2nd, 3rd etc. matches:

```py
list_1 = ['chest', 'test', 'west', 'nest']
list_2 = ['mike', 'bike', 'like', 'pike']
list_3 = ['hay', 'day', 'may', 'say']
word_list = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
pattern = r'\b' + r'(?:\b\s+'.join(fr"(?P<match_{i+1}>{'|'.join(w)})" for i, w in enumerate(word_list)) + r'\b' + ''.join(')?' for _ in range(1, len(word_list)))
```

For your sample data, this gives:

```
\b(?P<match_1>chest|test|west|nest)(?:\b\s+(?P<match_2>mike|bike|like|pike)(?:\b\s+(?P<match_3>hay|day|may|say)\b)?)?
```

You can see this working on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cbnXrK/1).

You can then use that regex with [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to find all matches in each text value, joining that result back to the original column.

```py
out = df[['text']].join(
        df['text'].str.extractall(pattern)
        .droplevel(1)
      ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

For your sample data that gives the following result:

```
                                                text match_1 match_2 match_3
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...   chest    bike     day
1   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    test    mike     NaN
2   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    west     NaN     NaN
3   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...    nest     NaN     NaN
4   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...    nest    bike     may
5   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    test    like     hay
6   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    west     NaN     NaN
7   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    west    like     NaN
```

Note that using variables `list_1`, `list_2` is not good programming practice, you should use a list of lists instead (like `word_list` above).

Comment: I have a couple follow up questions. Keeping the same conditions as above, If I wanted a match for the elements in list_3 no matter the position in the text, how would the regex pattern look like? (ex. aaa aa chest bike aa aaa day --> chest, bike day). Also, If an element from the first list (list_1) has already been matched, I would like to skip any other matches of the same word, how would the regex pattern look then?

Comment: @user22391597 that's quite a complicated change. I think it would be best to ask it as a new question. You should refer back to this question when you ask the new one (show the code you are using) and then give some good examples of the new desired output, particularly with regard to skipping matches of the same word

Comment: thank you for your reply! I will do just that.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'text': [' zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz ',
  ' aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aaaa aaa            ',
  ' ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ggg gggg west like ']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

`df1`

```
    text
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...
1   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...
```

---

**Step1**

at first make pattern

```
pat_list = ['(?P<match_{}>{})'.format(i, '|'.join(globals()["list_%i" % i])) for i in range(1, 4)]
```

`pat_list`

```
['(?P<match_1>chest|test|west|nest)',
 '(?P<match_2>mike|bike|like|pike)',
 '(?P<match_3>hay|day|may|say)']
```

I used a for loop to extract the values to be extracted into list_1, list_2, and list_3. If it is different from your mechanism, you can also create it manually.

**Step2**

next,extract pattern from the 'text' column of df1 and define the resulting DataFrame as df2.

```
df2 = df1['text'].str.extractall('|'.join(pat_list)).droplevel(1)
```

df2

```
match_1 match_2 match_3
0   chest   NaN     NaN
0   NaN     bike    NaN
0   NaN     NaN     day
0   test    NaN     NaN
0   NaN     mike    NaN
0   west    NaN     NaN
1   nest    NaN     NaN
1   nest    NaN     NaN
1   NaN     bike    NaN
1   NaN     NaN     may
2   test    NaN     NaN
2   NaN     like    NaN
2   NaN     NaN     hay
2   west    NaN     NaN
2   west    NaN     NaN
2   NaN     like    NaN
```

**Step3**

Compress the values of df2 in order and join with df1.

```
grp = df2['match_1'].notna().groupby(df2.index).cumsum()
df3 = df2.groupby([df2.index, grp]).first().droplevel(1)
out = df1[['text']].join(df3)
```

out

```
    text                                            match_1 match_2 match_3
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    chest   bike    day
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    test    mike    None
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    west    None    None
1   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...    nest    None    None
1   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...    nest    bike    may
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    test    like    hay
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    west    None    None
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    west    like    None
```

Comment: In step 1, my example just happened to have the three lists have the same length of 4. How would you got about step 1 if the lists were a lot bigger and had difference lengths?

Comment: @user22391597 The length of the list being 4 is irrelevant. You should check by adjusting the number of elements in the example list_1 and ask questions.

Comment: Note that this will match `test hay`, which it shouldn't do as there is no `match_2` present.

Answer (score 1):

You can craft a regex programmatically to use with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]
pats = [f"(?P<match_{i}>{'|'.join(l)})" for i, l in enumerate(lists, start=1)]
# ['(?P<match_1>chest|test|west|nest)',
#  '(?P<match_2>mike|bike|like|pike)',
#  '(?P<match_3>hay|day|may|say)']

pat = pats[-1]
for p in pats[-2::-1]:
    pat = f'{p}(?: +{pat})?'
# '(?P<match_1>chest|test|west|nest)(?: +(?P<match_2>mike|bike|like|pike)(?: +(?P<match_3>hay|day|may|say))?)?'

out = df['text'].str.extractall(pat).droplevel(1)
```

Output:

```
  match_1 match_2 match_3
0   chest    bike     day
0    test    mike     NaN
0    west     NaN     NaN
1    nest     NaN     NaN
1    nest    bike     may
2    test    like     hay
2    west     NaN     NaN
2    west    like     NaN
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FgTDRZ/1)

To join the result to the original DataFrame:

```
out = df.join(df['text'].str.extractall(pat).droplevel(1))
```

Output:

```
                                                text match_1 match_2 match_3
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...   chest    bike     day
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    test    mike     NaN
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zz...    west     NaN     NaN
1   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...    nest     NaN     NaN
1   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may a...    nest    bike     may
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    test    like     hay
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    west     NaN     NaN
2   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ...    west    like     NaN
```