# Regex matches from 3 lists based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, regex

This is a follow-up to this question [Matching several string matches from lists and making a new row for each match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041788/matching-several-string-matches-from-lists-and-making-a-new-row-for-each-match/77042125?noredirect=1#comment135827005_77042125)

One of the proposed solutions works as intended, however I was wondering if some slight adjustments can be made to achieve the following results. Keeping the same conditions as in the initial question linked above, if I wanted a match for the elements in list_3 no matter the position in the text, how would the new regex pattern look like? (keeping in mind that elements from list_1 and list_2 will always remain consecutive).

example:

```
list_1 = ['chest', 'test', 'west', 'nest']
list_2 = ['mike', 'bike', 'like', 'pike']
list_3 = ['hay', 'day', 'may', 'say']

text = 'zzz zzz chest bike zz zz day zzz'
```

The new regex expression should match on chest, bike and day. In the initial question, chest bike and day were consecutive. Here, they still are, but there is additional text between the first two matches (chest and bike) and the last match (day).

Finally,

Finally, If an element from the first list (list_1) has already been matched, I would like to skip any other matches of the same word.

example:

```
text = 'zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay zzz zz zz nest mike zzz'
```

this will match on west, like, say and nest, mike since west appears more than once in the text and since nest only appears once.

The text will still be in a data frame format and the output should also be in that format.

The current regex expression I am using is the following:

```
pattern = r'\b' + r'(?:\b\s+'.join(fr"(?P<match_{i+1}>{'|'.join(w)})" for i, w in enumerate(word_list)) + r'\b' + ''.join(')?' for _ in range(1, len(word_list)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the second match still have to be present for the third match to occur? e.g. would `'zzz zzz chest zz zz day zzz'` match?

Comment: Could there be more than 3 lists? If so, can there be extra words before words in the list other than the last one? e.g. if `list_4 = ['john', 'bill', 'fred']`, would `'zzz zzz chest bike zz zz day zzz fred zz'` match or must it be `'zzz zzz chest bike day zzz fred zz'`?

Comment: The second match does not have to present (its optional). So chest and day would match in that example. And No there are only three lists of varying lengths. The example I provided is a shortened version of each list. But each would have between 30 to 100 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a significant change to the regex to meet your new conditions. Firstly you need to make the third group optional, regardless of whether the second group is present or not. Secondly, to work with strings like `zzz zz west like zz zzz nest bike zz say zzz` you need to make sure that you don't look beyond a first word when you are searching for an optional third word (so that string would match `west, like` and `nest, bike, say`, not `west, like, say`). You can do that with a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). For your given sample data, the regex (with newlines for readability) would be:

```
\b(?P<match_1>chest|test|west|nest)
(?:\b\s+(?P<match_2>mike|bike|like|pike))?
(?:\b\s+(?:(?:(?!\b(?:chest|test|west|nest)\b).)*?)(?P<match_3>hay|day|may|say)\b)?
```

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IVHKik/2)

You can build your regex using this code:

```py
l1 = '|'.join(list_1)
l2 = '|'.join(list_2)
l3 = '|'.join(list_3)

pattern = fr"\b(?P<match_1>{l1})(?:\b\s+(?P<match_2>{l2}))?(?:\b\s+(?:(?:(?!\b(?:{l1})\b).)*?)(?P<match_3>{l3})\b)?"
```

You can then apply that to your dataframe as described in the previous question:

```py
out = df.join(
        df['text'].str.extractall(pattern)
        .droplevel(1)
      ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

With this sample input data:

```
                                                                    text
0        zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz zzzz west zzz zz
1                   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aaaa aaa
2        ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west ggg gggg west like
3                                       zzz zzz chest bike zz zz day zzz
4  zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay zzz zz zz nest mike zzz
5                                            zzz zzz chest zz zz day zzz
```

This gives:

```
                                                 text match_1 match_2 match_3
0   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz...   chest    bike     day
1   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz...    test    mike     NaN
2   zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz...    west     NaN     NaN
3   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aa...    nest     NaN     NaN
4   aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aa...    nest    bike     may
5   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west g...    test    like     hay
6   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west g...    west     NaN     NaN
7   ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west g...    west    like     NaN
8                    zzz zzz chest bike zz zz day zzz   chest    bike     day
9   zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay ...    west    like     say
10  zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay ...    west    bike     NaN
11  zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay ...    nest    mike     NaN
12                        zzz zzz chest zz zz day zzz   chest     NaN     day
```

You can then delete duplicates based on `text` and `match_1`:

```
out = out.drop_duplicates(subset=['text', 'match_1'], keep='first').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which gives your desired result:

```
                                                text match_1 match_2 match_3
0  zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz...   chest    bike     day
1  zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz...    test    mike     NaN
2  zzz zzz zz chest bike day zzzz z test mike zzz...    west     NaN     NaN
3  aaa aa aaa a nest aa aaaa aaa nest bike may aa...    nest     NaN     NaN
4  ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west g...    test    like     hay
5  ggg gg ggg ggg ggg test like hay ggg gg west g...    west     NaN     NaN
6                   zzz zzz chest bike zz zz day zzz   chest    bike     day
7  zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay ...    west    like     say
8  zzz zz west like say zz zzz west bike zzz lay ...    nest    mike     NaN
9                        zzz zzz chest zz zz day zzz   chest     NaN     day
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any resources for learning advanced regex techniques?

Comment: The rexegg site I linked to has a good reference, also the regex101 site I linked to is a good sandbox for playing in (and with an explanation of what the parts of the regex do).